# revalidating child UserControl that is in a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a parent UControl with a checkbox on it. Once checked it loads another UControl into a tabitem. I have validation on both parent and child UC’s. Validation works perfectly when creating a new record, but once the checkbox is unchecked and then rechecked, my validation border disappears on the child UC. I have a “Save” button on the parent UC. I noticed that this button does respond to the child validation in that it disables the button until all parent and child fields are filled. I can’t seem to get the red validation border to display when the re-checking of box is done. Can anyone please advise me on how to re-validate my child UC fields?

Called from parent UC

```
    private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        // The dependency object is valid if it has no errors, 
        //and all of its children (that are dependency objects) are error-free.
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) &&
            LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
            .OfType<DependencyObject>()
            .All(child => IsValid(child));
    }
```

Adding child UC from parent mycheckbox_checked event

```
    tabSafetyCageRequired.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    stackPanelSafetyCageDetail.Children.Clear();
    _currentSafetyCageDetail = childSafetyCageDetailUControl;
    stackPanelSafetyCageDetail.Children.Add(_currentSafetyCageDetail);
```

Removing child UC from parent mycheckbox_Unchecked event

```
    _currentSafetyCageDetail = childSafetyCageDetailUControl;
    stackPanelSafetyCageDetail.Children.Remove(_currentSafetyCageDetail);
    tabSafetyCageRequired.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

More code on request....

PS. I've come across some articles that suggest it's the "AdornerDecorator", but as I said above validation does work on first pass (new record) but loses it's red border on checking/unchecking checkbox.

Thanks in advance